# HTML title attribute making css :hover not work

Tags: html, css, hover, title

I have some code to make an arrow and im trying to add a title attribute to it. Here is the arrow code:

```css
#arrow-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
}

#arrow-right:hover {
  border-left: 10px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="arrow-right" title="text here"></div>
```

Before I added the 'title' attribute, it worked fine, changing to color to grey on hover, but after I added the 'title' attribute, the css color changing stopped working but the title started working. Is there any way to have both of these work at the same time?

Comment: No `;` in `id="arrow-right";`

Comment: it's getting grey, here in your demo. Not for you, even here on SO in the demo?

Comment: Hmm, its working here, just not on my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
<div id="arrow-right" ; title="text here"></div>
```

with

```
<div id="arrow-right" title="text here"></div>
```

Comment: That still didnt make it change color to grey

Comment: @Tabulate The question stated that the tite attribute made the hover function not work! I would help you if i could, but this code does not supply me with enough context or code to make an arrow be displayed. If you need further help regarding the hover function i would love to help you. otherwise i'd suggest you create  a new post with more information

Comment: Ill try to figure out the problem 1 more time. If i cant figure it out ill try and repost it with more context. Ill just have to narrow it down because the page had almost 1000 lines. Ill accept your answer for the given context

Comment: @Tabulate great! if you still have problems and decide to post a new question @ me in the comments and i will see what i can do

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had some js declaring the style in the element like:

```html
<div id="arrow-right" title="text here" style="border-right: 10px solid white;"></div>
```

Along with the style declared in the stylesheet and that broke it. I just had to remove the style declared in thr div and that fixed it